# BrokenPipeError: [WinError 109] The pipe has been ended during data extraction

Tags: multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, feature-extraction

I am new to multiprocessing in python.I am extracting some features from a list of 70,000 URLs. I have them from 2 different files. After the feature extraction process I pass the result to a list and then to a CSV file.

The code runs but then stops with the error.I tried to catch the error but it produced another one.

Python version = 3.5

```
from feature_extractor import Feature_extraction

import pandas as pd

from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame

import sys

from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

import threading as thread

from multiprocessing import Process,Manager,Array

import time

class main():

lst = None

def __init__(self):
    manager = Manager()
    self.lst = manager.list()
    self.dostuff()  
    self.read_lst()

def feature_extraction(self,url): 
        if self.lst is None:
            self.lst = []

        features = Feature_extraction(url) 
        self.lst.append(features.get_features())
        print(len(self.lst))



def Pool(self,url):   
        pool = ThreadPool(8) 
        results = pool.map(self.feature_extraction, url)

def dostuff(self):
    df = pd.read_csv('verified_online.csv',encoding='latin-1')
    df['label'] = df['phish_id'] * 0
    mal_urls = df['url']

    df2 = pd.read_csv('new.csv') 
    df2['label'] = df['phish_id']/df['phish_id']
    ben_urls = df2['urls']
    t = Process(target=self.Pool,args=(mal_urls,))
    t2 = Process(target=self.Pool,args=(ben_urls,))
    t.start()
    t2.start()
    t.join()
    t2.join 

def read_lst(self):
    nw_df = DataFrame(list(self.lst))

    nw_df.columns = ['Redirect count','ssl_classification','url_length','hostname_length','subdomain_count','at_sign_in_url','exe_extension_in_request_url','exe_extension_in_landing_url',
                        'ip_as_domain_name','no_of_slashes_in requst_url','no_of_slashes_in_landing_url','no_of_dots_in_request_url','no_of_dots_in_landing_url','tld_value','age_of_domain',
                        'age_of_last_modified','content_length','same_landing_and_request_ip','same_landing_and_request_url']
    frames = [df['label'],df2['label']]
    new_df = pd.concat(frames)
    new_df = new_df.reset_index()
    nw_df['label'] = new_df['label']
    nw_df.to_csv('dataset.csv', sep=',', encoding='latin-1')

 if __name__ == '__main__':



start_time = time.clock()
try:
    main()

except BrokenPipeError:
    print("broken pipe....")
    pass

print (time.clock() - start_time, "seconds")
```

Error Traceback

```
Process Process-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 312, in _recv_bytes
    nread, err = ov.GetOverlappedResult(True)
BrokenPipeError: [WinError 109] The pipe has been ended

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "F:\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "H:\Projects\newoproject\src\main.py", line 33, in Pool
    results = pool.map(self.feature_extraction, url)
  File "F:\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 260, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "F:\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 608, in get
    raise self._value
  File "F:\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "F:\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "H:\Projects\newoproject\src\main.py", line 26, in feature_extraction
    self.lst.append(features.get_features())
  File "<string>", line 2, in append
  File "F:\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 717, in _callmethod
    kind, result = conn.recv()
  File "F:\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 250, in recv
    buf = self._recv_bytes()
  File "F:\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 321, in _recv_bytes
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

Comment: I have trimmed the unacceptable begging material from your post; [please read this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) - all of it, thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot @halfer

Answer (score 4):

My response is late and does not address the posted problem directly; but hopefully will provide a clue to others who encounter similar errors.

Errors that I encountered:
BrokenPipeError
WinError 109 The pipe has been ended & 
WinError 232 The pipe is being closed

Observed with Python 36 on Windows 7, when:
(1) the same async function was submitted multiple times, each time with a different instance of a multiprocessing data store, a Queue in my case (multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()) 
AND
(2) the references to the Queues were saved in short-life local variables in the enveloping function.

The errors were occurring despite the fact that the Queues, shared with the successfully spawned and executing async-functions, had items and would still be in active use (put() & get()) at the time of exception.

The error consistently occurred when the same async_func was called the 2nd time with a 2nd instance of the Queue.  Immediately after apply_async() of the function, the connection to the 1st Queue supplied to the async_func the 1st time, would get broken.

The issue got resolved when the references to the Queues were saved in non-overlapping (like a Queue-list) & longer-life variables  (like variables returned to functions higher in the call-stack) in the enveloping function.